# How to import a module in a sub-sub directory

Tags: python, import, module

Here is my code structure

I have included some open-source package as a submodule in my project repo. In `main-app-dir/api/server.py`, I implement RESTful api request handlers. In one of my handlers, I am trying to use a function in `main-app-dir/open-source-package/open-source-package/api/response.py` file.

```
main-app-dir
- app.py
- api
-- __init__.py
-- server.py
- open-source-package
-- requirements.txt
-- open-source-package
--- __init__.py
--- api
---- __init__.py
---- response.py
```

Would it be possible to achieve what I want to do without having to modify anything in `open-source-package`?

Comment: Don't use submodules to use a third-party library.  Install it into your Python environment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from open-source-package.api.response import <function_name>
```

Comment: add an explanation to improve answer quality

Comment: It throws a `ModuleNotFoundError`. I believe this is because the open-source-package doesn't have an __init__.py in its main directory

Comment: @DayeongLee Your question showed there is an \_\_init__.py file in the folders. In order to import the file as a module, that file is required. If there isn't one there, you can simple create a blank one. You can read more in the [import documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).